# Big query not converting the time but just changing the time zone

Tags: python, datetime, google-bigquery

Step # 1 -- In my big query table, I created (in SQL) and saved a field (create_time) in Pacific time (America/Los_Angeles) and it appears like this -> `2022-05-31T06:07:46.044000` .

update: This create time field is created from a UTC time field in big query table. I am just doing the following to create the create_time field -> `datetime(existing_create_time, America/Los_Angeles )`, where the existing one is in UTC.

Step #2 -- Now in a python script, I am reading step#1 table (using client.query() method of big query), the create_time along with few other variables, performing some operations on other fields (create_time is untouched) and saving these back to a different big query table (using the '`load_table_from_dataframe`' method in BQ to save pandas dataframe to big query table).

update: After reading into the pandas dataframe, the value is a timestamp like `Timestamp('2022-05-31 06:07:46.044000')`

Output from Step #2  -- Now, in the saved BQ table from the step#2, I see the create_time field appears like this --> `2022-05-31 06:07:46.044000 UTC`

update: so the big query table is created by the pandas dataframe, and the data type associated withthe  BQ output date field is `timestamp`. I have no control over this data type as it is automatically created by `load_table_From_Dataframe()` method

The problem with the step#2 output is, Big query is just changing the time zone of the  create_time to UTC without converting the time to UTC. For example, if I initially have 10:00 PST, when actually converting to UTC, it should be 17:00 UTC. But when saving the output in step#2, big query is saving the time as 10:00 UTC (changing the time zone without converting the time to the corresponding time zone).

Is there a way to fix this -> have BQ convert the time as well, along with time zone change (or) other alternative is to explicitly state in python that the incoming create_Time (while reading it from big query) is in pacific time stamp   ?

Comment: Can you confirm a few of the following; 1. How are you initially creating the `create_time` field? 2. After reading it into your df frame what is the value? 3.what is the data type associated with the final output in bigquery?

Comment: @DanielZagales I have responded to the your questions with the sections marked as 'update:' in the above question. Thank you

Comment: @DanielZagales 
I Solved the issue by explicitly stating the time zone when reading the BQ data in my python job in step #2 . Used ->   timestamp(create_time, 'America/Los_Angeles')

Comment: @tjt can you post your solution as answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved the issue by explicitly stating the time zone when reading the BQ data in my python job in step #2 . Used -> timestamp(create_time, 'America/Los_Angeles')